# python list comprehension with a string

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm running into a funny scenario with list comprehensions and strings. Here's a simplified example of the scenario:

This:

```
banned = ['apple', 'pear']
sentence = 'I will eat an apple'    
if(not x in sentence for x in banned): print('ok')
```

Returns:

```
ok
```

Even though 'apple' appears in the sentence. Have I written the comprehension incorrectly? If any word in 'banned' is in 'sentence', 'ok' shouldn't print.

Comment: A non empty list (whatever the values) is truthy

Comment: you're after the `all` keyword - `if all(not x in sentence for x in banned): print('ok')`

Comment: it's a bit clearer if you use 'x not in sentence'

Comment: I'd probably use `if not any(x in sentence for ...)` instead of `all(not x...)`, just makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following part:

```
(not x in sentence for x in banned)
```

Is a generator expression that will be evaluated as True, regardless of whatever the content is.

If you want to check the truth value of multiple items you may want to use either `any` or `all` functions based on your problem.

In this case it seems that you need `all()`:

```
banned = ['apple', 'pear']
sentence = 'I will eat an apple'    
if all(x not in sentence for x in banned):
    print('ok')
```

Also, note that the part `x not in sentence` will check the membership within the entire string, not its words. That says, if one of the words within the input string is contain a word within `banned` list it will return True. Like `pearl` which is contain the word `pear`.

One way for getting around that problem is to check the membership in splitted text or use regular expressions.

Another alternative would be using `set` and intersection:

```
banned = {'apple', 'pear'}  # use set instead of list
sentence = 'I will eat an apple'
if banned.intersection(sentence.split()):
    print('ok')
```

As @Jean-FrançoisFabre mentioned it's better to use `set.isdisjoint()` rather than `set.intersection` since you just want to check the intersection.

```
banned = {'apple', 'pear'}  # use set instead of list
sentence = 'I will eat an apple'
if not banned.isdisjoint(sentence.split()):
    print('ok')
```

Comment: `if banned.intersection(sentence.split()):` creates a `set`, which is wasteful. Better use `not banned.isdisjoint()` as a condition.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `isdisjoint()` doesn't return a correct result for this problem. Try `banned.isdisjoint('apple pear banana'.split())`.

Comment: I wrote `not {'apple', 'pear'}.isdisjoint('apple pear banana'.split())`. not isdisjoint means intersection is not empty. That works.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, indeed it return True if two sets have a null intersection. Thanks for note though.